# Error while converting .ui file to .py file in QT

Tags: python, pyqt

Error while converting .ui file to .py file in QT

I am getting error while converting .ui to .py file in QT.

Error in input file: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 1

I had used the same command before and it worked fine for me. But right now I am stuck with this error. I am sure i have save .ui file before converting to .py file.

Please help as this issue is blocking.

Comment: To get help, you have to give more information about what you did to get the error. Additionally, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I just designed a ui file with few labels and push buttons in QT designer. I want to write the code in python so tried converting .ui to .py file. It is not happening and throwing this error.

Comment: And the error is very clear: The input file is not well-formed. So you have to make it well formed. If you want to get help, you should edit your question and provide at least: - the input file, - the command(s) you invoked to get the error.

Comment: pyuic4 -x mainwindow.ui > mainwindow.py    also i tried using pycui4 -o mainwindow.ui mainwindow,py

Comment: With my examples, this command works. But I see that you are new to stackoverflow, so I try to ask you again, to provide a [mcve]. Please edit your question accordingly. You may also want to have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @ArpithaM use `pyuic4 mainwindow.ui -o mainwindow.py -x`